# Google Maps API Nodes

Tags: java, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, kml

I looked through the entire Google Maps API reference list earlier, maybe I'm just being stupid but I couldn't find anything relating to what I need to accomplish.

I wish to import some form of XML data from Google Maps that has only roads. My plan is to use the XML file to draw the roads to a 2D or 3D environment in Java using OpenGL. That's the easy bit on my part.

The closest thing I found to what I need is KML data but as far as I could tell that is only for markers and not road maps. Sorry if my question is vague but if it is let me know and I will try to elaborate.

Elevation data would also be useful for the 3D part but it is not necessarily needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The road network on Google Maps is not available for download.  Sounds like that is what you are looking for.

Comment: Yeah that is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for letting me know. Do you know what the copyright legislation is like for using static maps? I'm thinking of using pixel mapping of static maps to generate XML with PHP so I can import that data into my Java program.

Comment: IANAL - scraping Google Maps data is against the [Terms of Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#tos)..

Comment: the US census produces Tiger data that contains roads, and it is free to download. Static Maps fall under the Terms of Service which prevent you from scraping the data out of them, but you should read the Terms.